# How to use Flutter, MongoDB and Docker together in app development?

Tags: json, mongodb, flutter, docker, dart

With a colleague of mine, we're building an app written in Dart with Flutter on Android Studio. We've arrived at the point where we need to start integrating a database to collect and send user filled data, and so we chose MongoDB which will be integrated into Docker so that our app is ready to function on multiple devices. Since we will have many users and each of them will be entering their own data, we have a lot of parameters to take into account so we're creating a JSON skeleton to map out the structure of what data goes where. The obstacle is we have no clue what the best way is to approach MongoDB-Docker integration with our Android Studio code, as it is our first time using MongoDB and Docker. Any good tips or resources that could put us on the right track ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi your real question should be : what will you use in beetween those two ? You should (I guess) create an API to simplify and securise your user-DB interactions.
If you're not familiar with those principles a quick reasearch should help.

If you want to continue without any API, you should put many effort into having a VERY clean code as your app will have a lot of information inside its source code and proceed to create a documentation. Also you could use an ORM.